# Symfony2's YamlFileLoader: Looked for namespace "mybundle_tools", found none

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, symfony-2.8

EDIT: after deleting the YamlFileLoader lines, my processed Configuration is empty (array(0) { }):

**my new Extension**

```
<?php
namespace MyProject\MyBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\Extension;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;

class MyProjectMyExtension extends Extension
{
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $configuration = new Configuration();
        $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration,$configs);

        var_dump($config); // array(0) { } 

        /*...*/
    }
}
```

**associated error**

```
ContextErrorException in MyProjectMyExtension.php line 22: Notice: Undefined index: cachedir

in MyProjectMyExtension.php line 22
at ErrorHandler->handleError('8', 'Undefined index: cachedir', '/home/jeff/Projets/MyProject/src/MyProject/MyBundle/DependencyInjection/MyProjectMyExtension.php', '22', array('configs' => array(array()), 'container' => object(ContainerBuilder), 'configuration' => object(Configuration), 'config' => array())) in MyProjectMyExtension.php line 22
at MyProjectMyExtension->load(array(array()), object(ContainerBuilder)) in MergeExtensionConfigurationPass.php line 59
at MergeExtensionConfigurationPass->process(object(ContainerBuilder)) in MergeExtensionConfigurationPass.php line 39
at MergeExtensionConfigurationPass->process(object(ContainerBuilder)) in Compiler.php line 104
at Compiler->compile(object(ContainerBuilder)) in ContainerBuilder.php line 598
at ContainerBuilder->compile() in Kernel.php line 514
at Kernel->initializeContainer() in Kernel.php line 133
at Kernel->boot() in Kernel.php line 182
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in app_dev.php line 27
```

It seems my configuration is still really broken. Thank you for your comment; do you have an idea of what is wrong here?

---

I am stuck on a Symfony 2.8 Third-Party Bundle Configuration problem.

I am creating the custom configuration for my bundle and it seems YamlFileLoader cannot accept what I wrote in my config.yml:

```
InvalidArgumentException in YamlFileLoader.php line 399: There is no extension able to load the configuration for "mybundle_tools" (in /home/jeff/Projets/MyProject/src/MyProject/MyBundle/DependencyInjection/../Resources/config/config.yml). Looked for namespace "mybundle_tools", found none
```

I failed to make this custom Configuration work for days and I think there may be also some mistakes in my Configuration.php and my Extension.php files.

Could you help me to find where I did a mistake?

Thank you per advance! :)

Here is my code:

**services.yml**

```
services:
    mybundle.weather:
        class: MyProject\MyBundle\Service\Weather
        arguments:  ['%mybundle_tools%']
```

**config.yml**

```
mybundle_tools:
    cachedir: '%kernel.cache_dir%/mybundle'
    weather:
        cachefile: '%kernel.cache_dir%/mybundle/weather.json'
        apikey: 'myapikey'
        apiurlbase: 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q='
```

**Configuration.php**

```
<?php
namespace MyProject\MyBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Builder\TreeBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\ConfigurationInterface;

class Configuration implements ConfigurationInterface
{
    public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
    {
        $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
        $rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('mybundle_tools');

            $rootNode
            ->children()
                ->scalarNode('cachedir')->end()
                ->arrayNode('weather')
                    ->children()
                        ->scalarNode('cachefile')->end()
                        ->scalarNode('apikey')->end()
                        ->scalarNode('apiurlbase')->end()
                    ->end()
                ->end()
            ->end()
        ;

        return $treeBuilder;
    }
}
```

**MyProjectMyExtension.php**

```
<?php
namespace MyProject\MyBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\Extension;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\YamlFileLoader;
use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;
class MyProjectMyExtension extends Extension
{
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        var_dump($configs);
        $loader = new YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('config.yml');

        $configuration = new Configuration();

        $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration,$configs);

        $container->setParameter('mybundle_tools.cachedir', $config['cachedir']);
        $container->setParameter('mybundle_tools.weather.cachefile', $config['weather']['cachefile']);
        $container->setParameter('mybundle_tools.weather.apikey', $config['weather']['apikey']);
        $container->setParameter('mybundle_tools.weather.apiurlbase', $config['weather']['apiurlbase']);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have the configuration of your bundle in `load` method. If you use the `processConfiguration` like that, you will get your bundle confs.

Remember, load method only contains your bundle configuration. If you want to access full config, you need the implement `prepend` interface.

```
public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
{ 
    $configuration = new Configuration();
    $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

    ....
}
```